# list all computer in network starting with particular name

Tags: c#

Can I list all the computers which is in network which starts with particular name?
e.g. suppose below given computers are shared in network-
(keyboard, monitor, monitor1, monitor235, PC6, keyboard2, PC8, PC6, PC2)

I am using below code to list all the computers in network-

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
        {
            if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
            {
                list.Add(computer.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can I list all the PC which starts with name "PC"? 
i.e PC6, PC8, PC2

Comment: Your actual problem is how to *match strings*. Googling for that would give you numerous results (`String.Contains`, `String.StartsWith`, `Regex.Match`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Linq?

```
root.Children
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("PC"))
    .Select(x => x.Name);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)